# Combine points within given radius in R to a centroid

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, centroid

I feel like this can not be too hard. I know `hclust()` and `cutree()` but how do I obtain the coordinates of the centroids where no points distance from it is higher than a given radius? I know that points within range of the centroid may be already belong to a centroid not within range. I am fine with that.

```
set.seed(1)
data <- matrix(runif(100),ncol=2)
plot(data) 
dclust <- hclust(dist(data),method="centroid")
cutree(dclust,h=0.1)
```

`cutree(...,h=0.1)` will already fail as the height of `dclust` is not ordered.

Comment: This sounds more like k-means clustering rather than hierarchical clustering. You could incrementally increase k until the worst distance from a point to its cluster's centroid is within the radius you selected.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you are trying to do. The kmeans() function is probably what you want, but do the centroid positions (and the number of centroids) come from from the data or do you have them independent of the data? Can an observation be unmatched to a cluster? If you can always add a centroid (cluster), then you can set any worst distance you want, including zero! Also kmeans() does not give unique results unless you provide the centroids at the start. If the centroids come from your data, there may be multiple solutions.

Comment: Let's not talk about observations. I have some data from the OpenStreetMap and the coordinates of nodes where two or more streets meet each other. As there are intersections (as we humans see them) with a lot of those above mentioned nodes within short distance (imagine a street with to separate lanes meeting another one) I want a point which represents those nodes for visualization for example.

Answer (score 0):

Using your data and running kmeans with 25 groups produces the following results. Is this what you are getting at?

```
Example <- kmeans(data, 25)
plot(data, type="n")
text(Example$centers, unlist(dimnames(Example$centers)), col="red")
text(data, as.character(Example$cluster), cex=.75)
cdist <- sqrt((data[,1] - Example$centers[Example$cluster, 1])^2 + 
     (data[, 2] - Example$centers[Example$cluster, 2])^2)
names(cdist) <- 1:50
cdist
```

The last three lines compute and display the distance of each point to the centroid to which it has been assigned.